# Facebook share_open_graph: remove message and change button text

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-share

I'm looking for help for sharing an open graph story (`"video.rates"` action on `"video.movie"` object), through the action `share_open_graph`.
It works, but I would like to customize it.

I attach 3 images to post:

- [album with three images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0jK8.jpg)

In the first image the user assigns a vote and writes a brief review (`"Beautiful movie"`) to the movie; in the second image the user has the ability to insert an additional comment (`"this text will be hidden"`); in the third image the user published the open graph story correctly (review, vote and url are ok), but the last comment has disappeared and you see a `"Salva"` button.

I have two questions:

- I don't understand why Facebook Dialog ask the last comment (when the user writes `"this text will be hidden"`) if it does not show it. Can I remove the inclusion of the latter comment, in Facebook Share dialog?
- Can I customize or remove the `"Salva"` button on the open graph story?

This is my Javascript code:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'video.rates',
    action_properties: {
        "rating:value": vote,
        "rating:scale": 10,
        "review_text": comment,
        "movie": url
    }
}, function (response) {
    callback(response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Aurelio, about your second question, "Can I customize or remove the "Salva" button on the open graph story?". The "Salva" button appears on the open graph story because your object inherits from business, it must inherit from object. When you do this, the salva button should automatically disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found anything in Facebook's documentation that hints towards a way to hide the text input field in the dialog.

The fact that any text that is entered there will not be shown if your OG action has a free form text property already (like the `review_text` property on `video.likes`) seems to be a bug.

I recommend that you create a bug report with Facebook at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/